# What triggers the hallucinations (or are they random)?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-3

I have been watching FNAF 3, and hallucinations seem to be happening at random, seemingly without any patterns.

So do hallucinations happen at random, or is there something that triggers them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you fail to keep your air ventilation up, and when it does go down, the hallucinations will become more and more frequent.  The Phone Guy tells you on Day 1 to make sure the ventilation stays on otherwise you'll see things.

Hallucinations are only more common as soon as the ventilation stops working.  You'll notice this visually by flashing red lights around your room.

Answer (score 1):

- Hallucination Freddy: he will walk at the hall of the glass window, use your system or camera to avoid his attack.
- Hallucination Chica: **don't** view cam 7 or 6 for too long, or else you will see her face on the arcade. She will later appear on your left side of the office to jumpscare you.
- Hallucination BB: just like Chica, but don’t view cam 9 for too long or else he will jumpscare you.

  (Keep in mind they can’t kill you in FNAF 3.)

---

- Hallucination Foxy: watching the camera for too long will cause him to attack on your left side of the office.
- Hallucination Mangle: when she appears on cam, close it, or she will cause an audio that will make Springtrap not hear your audio lures. You can also avoid her by changing cams.
- Hallucination puppet: don’t view cam 8 for too long or the original puppet will appear and jumpscare you, plus, he will block your view.